# append series in a for loop python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I append the pd.series output in a loop

Input

```
for hours in fun(data, 24*10):
    model.fit(hours)
    df['output'] = pd.Series(model.predict(hours))
```

I want something like this

```
lst=[]

for hours in fun(data, 24*10):
    model.fit(hours)
    x = pd.Series(model.predict(hours))
    lst.append(x)

df['output'] = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Comment: Append to a list and after for loop create a `pd.Series` from the list. This is more performant.

Comment: Tried. It didn't work the way I wanted. I updated the code.

Comment: You should add desired output

Answer (score 1):

pd.concat should work:

```py
lst=[]

for hours in fun(data, 24*10):
    model.fit(hours)
    x = pd.Series(model.predict(hours))
    lst.append(x)

df['output'] = pd.concat(lst, axis=0)
```